# react-native expo como gerar uma url de redirecionamento com AuthSession.startAsync({ authUrl})

Tags: react-native, expo

```js
import * as AuthSession from 'expo-auth-session';

const response = AuthSession.startAsync({
        authUrl: `${api.defaults.baseURL}/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}&scope=${SCOPE}`,
      });

      console.log(response);
```

resposta do log

```js
Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X": null,
}
```

quando olho o log, não vem a sujestão do REDIRECT_URI para usar, então sempre cai no erro 404, como eu crio uma url para redirecionar?

Answer (score 0):

Vc precisa rodar o App no modo tunnel! Aí dá uma olhada no seu terminal...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso isso não funcione vc irá precisar deslogar do Expo CLI rodando o seguinte comando:

- **expo logout**